# Django/Python process that checks database object status

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I am building a django app that has some functionality to send email/SMS notifications. These notifications should be sent asynchronously/in the background. I have already come across celery and played with it a bit and I think it's totally awesome. Now, the notifications are stored in a model, where one of the fields 'status' indicates whether a notification has been sent or not. I currently need a way to monitor the status of notifications in my database table to check if the status is 0 - not sent or 1 - sent.If the status is 0, a celery task should be invoked to send the notifications with status 0. So, what is the best way to monitor the DB table? A daemon maybe?

Comment: What's responsible for putting the model into a state so that a notification needs to be sent in the first place? Couldn't you trigger the Celery job from there?

Comment: If it's not urgent that notifications are sent shortly after the status is set to 0 you could use cron to set up a scheduled job and specify at which times it should run.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's not the model that's in a state...a notification is. Depending on it's status i.e. 0 (not sent) or 1 (sent).

Comment: @nejc92, it's urgent that after setting a notification status to 0, it is immediately sent.

Comment: Sure, but my point is that something is setting the notification status to 0. So it seems to me that it is that same code that should also be triggering the Celery job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.  If you actually want to monitor the table, look at [celery perioidic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), which can run a celery task at defined intervals.

You could also trigger the task on model save, either with a [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-save) or with an overridden [model save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).  This way you can trigger the event immediately, you're not limited to the resolution of the periodic task.

Comment: Isn't the post-save signal synchronous?

Comment: and, the problem with a scheduler is that it executes at particular intervals. I want to do this in such a way that when a new notification is saved with status 0, the task is invoked and the notification is sent.

Comment: Post save is synchronous, but you can use it to trigger the celery task that sends the notification, making the sending asynchronous.

Comment: I think the celery periodic tasks do it for me for now...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [event scheduler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)